# Using げ to turn adjectives and nouns into adverbs

Tags: grammar

> 「自慢げに話す」「得意げに話す」「誇らしげに話す」

Is this げ a simple way to turn adjectives and nouns into adverbs?
(are the first two examples nouns turned into adverbs, or were they adjectives as well to begin with?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

～げ, although usually written with hiragana, can also be written as ～気, and means something like "have an air of...". These can be used as na-adjectives:

> 自慢げな態度 an attitude with an air of boastfulness
>   得意げに話す speak with an air of (over-)confidence
>   悲しげな顔 a face with an air of sadness

Some can also be used as nouns, but beware, not all of the ones that can be used as na-adjectives are used as nouns. The nouns are most commonly used with ない (but other uses also occur).

> 大人{おとな}げ(が)ない immature (no air of matureness)
>   かわいげ(が)ない impertinent (lit. no air of cuteness)

Comment: I saw a comment on a different ,related question saying that げに cannot be used with na-adjectives. (Topic: "What is ~げに suffix actually?" Axioplase's comment to their own answer) Is he wrong about the usage of げに?

Answer (score 2):

`自慢`　is a suru-noun, `得意` is an adjectival-noun (na-adjective), and `誇らし` is the root of an i-adjective. I think `げ` turns them all into adjectival-nouns. A clear diagnostics is that you can create the attributive form with `な`.

> 自慢げな態度
>   得意気な態度
>   誇らしげな態度