# Can anyone explain 涼しげで?

Tags: grammar

In reference to Japanese sweets (わらび餅), I found this sentence:

> 見た目も透明感があり、涼しげで夏にピッタリです。
>
> Its clear and cool appearance makes it perfect for summer.

Is 涼しげで two words?
涼しい　＋　で？

Could I also write the sentence this way, or would it make it grammatically incorrect or change the meaning?

> 見た目も透明感があり、涼しくて夏にピッタリです。

Comment: [You seem to have asked a similar question before](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4768/542)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

げ can be attached to the stem of a selected set of subjective i-adjectives or nouns to turn them into a na-adjective meaning "seemingly ...". With adjectives that you cannot use this, you can use そう instead. With nouns, you cannot replace it with そう.

> 涼しそう 涼しげ 自慢 自慢げ

Your rewrite will change the meaning.

This belongs to derivational morphology, and is not usually considered part of syntax.

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting. In my experience I hear 涼しそう more than 涼しげ . What is the tone of this conjugation? Is it stuffy or formal or archaic or colloquial in feel?

Comment: I don't see the "seemingly" nuance in these examples- 涼しげな潮風
cool sea breeze
涼しげな音
refreshingly cool sound

(are they wrong?)

Comment: @yadokari They are wrong as translations.

Comment: Also, 「げ」 in this usage is 「[気]{げ}」.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes.