# Where does げ come from?

Tags: grammar, meaning, etymology

Where does ～げ come from?  For example in

> 地震の影響で工場を閉じることになったと説明する社長は**悔しげ**だった。

it is supposed to mean that we get a slight impression that the manager was "regretful" while explaining why the factory had to stop.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/using-to-turn-adjectives-and-nouns-into-adverbs/4772#4772

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ~げに suffix actually?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/what-is-%e3%81%92%e3%81%ab-suffix-actually) or [Using げ to turn adjectives and nouns into adverbs](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4768/using-%e3%81%92-to-turn-adjectives-and-nouns-into-adverbs?lq=1).